# How to get the cdf when the random variable take probability p for some distribution and 1-p for some other distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose that a random variable $X$, with probability $p$ of being distributed as uniform over $(−1/2, 1/2)$ and with probability $1 − p$ of being distributed as uniform over $(0, 1)$.

Find the cumulative distribution function (cdf) and the probability density function (pdf) of $X$.

In the solution, it said $F_X (x)=pF_1(x)+ (1-p) F_2 (x)$. Is this general rule?

Comment: Yes.  Assuming that the _choosing_ random variable is independent of the 2 _chosen_ rvs.

Comment: It is called a [mixture distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution)